# c# drop down list in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, webforms

I am a grid view that I have that I can edit, update, delete from.  I can manually add a drop down and have the selected value populate correctly, but I want to be able to populate the drop down from the database (and show the selected value correctly) when editing it.

I have tried a bunch of searches/options but can not find a way to make it work.

My code is below:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateData();
            lblMessage.Text = "";
        }

        string sSQL = "";

        // populate drop downs
        sSQL = @"SELECT ErrorTypeLookupID as Value, ErrorDescription as DisplayText
            FROM BabelFish.dbo.ErrorTypeLookup (NOLOCK)
            WHERE ErrorType = 'Category'
            ";
        //ORDER BY OrderBy, ErrorDescription";

        new DatabaseConnection().PopulateListBoxFromDB(sSQL, "", lstNewResolutionCategory);


        sSQL = @"SELECT ErrorTypeLookupID as Value, ErrorDescription as DisplayText
            FROM BabelFish.dbo.ErrorTypeLookup (NOLOCK)
            WHERE ErrorType = 'Severity'
            ";
        //ORDER BY OrderBy, ErrorDescription";

        new DatabaseConnection().PopulateListBoxFromDB(sSQL, "", lstNewResolutionSeverity);


    }//end page load


    protected void DeleteRow(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        var ResolutionsID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;

        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex] as GridViewRow;

        string sSQL = "Delete from BabelFish.dbo.Resolutions where ResolutionsID = @ResolutionsID";

        SqlCommand sCommand = new SqlCommand(sSQL);

        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResolutionsID", ResolutionsID);

        // run delete
        new DatabaseConnection().RSExecute(sCommand);

        lblMessage.Text = "Record deleted successfully !";

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        this.PopulateData();

    }




    protected void UpdateRow(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        var ResolutionsID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;

        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex] as GridViewRow;

        TextBox txtResolutionDescription = row.FindControl("txtResolutionDescription") as TextBox;
        DropDownList drpErrorCategoryID = row.FindControl("ErrorCategory") as DropDownList;


        string sSQL = @"Update BabelFish.dbo.Resolutions set 
                    ResolutionDescription = @ResolutionDescription,
                    UserIDSolved = ISNULL(BabelFish.dbo.fn_GetUserIDFromTeamMemberTable(@UserIDSolved), BabelFish.dbo.fn_GetUserIDFromTeamMemberTable(REPLACE(@UserIDSolved, '-', ''))), 
                    DateTimeSolved = ISNULL(DateTimeSolved, GetDate())                        
                    where ResolutionsID = @ResolutionsID";

        SqlCommand sCommand = new SqlCommand(sSQL);

        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResolutionDescription", txtResolutionDescription.Text.Trim());
        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResolutionsID", ResolutionsID);
        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserIDSolved", UserID);

        // run update
        new DatabaseConnection().RSExecute(sCommand);


        lblMessage.Text = "Record updated successfully !";

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        this.PopulateData();

    }




    private void PopulateData()
    {
        string sSQL = @"SELECT
                ResolutionsID, ErrorTableID, BabelFish.dbo.fn_GetUserNameFromTeamMemberTable(UserIDSolved) as UserIDSolved, 
                DateTimeSolved, ResolutionDescription, ResolutionCategory, ResolutionSeverity, IsActive
                FROM BabelFish.dbo.Resolutions (NOLOCK)
                Where ErrorTableID = '" + ErrorTableID + "'";

        DataTable dt = DatabaseAccessing.DatabaseConnection.GetDataTable(sSQL);

        // only do if more then 1 row exists
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;

            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "No Rows Exist.";
        }




    }


    protected void AddRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get values to add to database
        string txtResolutionDescription = txtNewResolutionDescription.Text.ToString();

        string lstCategoryID = lstNewResolutionCategory.SelectedValue;
        string lstSeverityID = lstNewResolutionSeverity.SelectedValue;

        string sSQL = @"INSERT INTO BabelFish.dbo.Resolutions (
            ErrorTableID, UserIDSolved, DateTimeSolved, ResolutionDescription, 
            ResolutionCategory, ResolutionSeverity, IsActive
        )

        VALUES (
            @ErrorTableID, ISNULL(BabelFish.dbo.fn_GetUserIDFromTeamMemberTable(@UserIDSolved), BabelFish.dbo.fn_GetUserIDFromTeamMemberTable(REPLACE(@UserIDSolved, '-', ''))), 
            GetDate(), @ResolutionDescription,
            @ResolutionCategory, @ResolutionSeverity, 1
        )";


        SqlCommand sCommand = new SqlCommand(sSQL);

        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ErrorTableID", ErrorTableID);
        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserIDSolved", UserID);
        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResolutionDescription", txtResolutionDescription);
        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResolutionCategory", lstCategoryID);
        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResolutionSeverity", lstSeverityID);


        // run update
        new DatabaseConnection().RSExecute(sCommand);


        lblMessage.Text = "Record successfully added!";

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        this.PopulateData();
    }


    protected void EditRow(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        this.PopulateData();

        /*
        //not working, ddl is NULL
        var ddl = (DropDownList)GridView1.FindControl("selResolutionSeverity");

        string sSQL = @"SELECT ErrorTypeLookupID as Value, ErrorDescription as DisplayText
            FROM BabelFish.dbo.ErrorTypeLookup (NOLOCK)
            WHERE ErrorType = 'Severity' ";


        DataSet DS = new DatabaseAccessing.DatabaseConnection().DS(sSQL);

        ddl.DataSource = DS;
        ddl.DataTextField = "DisplayText";
        ddl.DataValueField = "Value";
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select --", "0"));
         * */
    }



    protected void CancelEditRow(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        this.PopulateData();
    }


    protected void ChangePage(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        this.PopulateData();

    }



    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" EnableViewState="false" />

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        Width="100%" 
        OnRowEditing="EditRow" 
        OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEditRow"
        OnRowUpdating="UpdateRow" 
        DataKeyNames="ResolutionsID" 
        OnRowDeleting="DeleteRow" 
        AllowPaging="true"
        PageSize="50" 
        OnPageIndexChanging="ChangePage"            

        >

    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
            </ItemTemplate>

            <EditItemTemplate>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />

                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />

            </EditItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ResolutionsID" DataField="ResolutionsID" ReadOnly="true" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ResolutionDescription">
            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("ResolutionDescription")%></ItemTemplate>

            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtResolutionDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ResolutionDescription") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="UserIDSolved" DataField="UserIDSolved" ReadOnly="true" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("ResolutionCategory")%>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <EditItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="selResolutionCategory" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("ResolutionCategory") %>'>         
                        <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select One --" Value="0" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="cat1" Value="1" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="cat2" Value="2" />        
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Severity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("ResolutionSeverity")%>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <EditItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="selResolutionSeverity" runat="server">                                     
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" ForeColor="Red" CommandName="Delete" />
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField> 


    </Columns>

    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#efefef" />

    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />

    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />

    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />

    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />

    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />

    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />

    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to want to use OnRowDataBound. Here is the example of how I populate one of my drop downs within my gridview.

```
protected void gvVehicle_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvVehicleTEMP.Rows)
        {
            DropDownList ddlLocation = ((DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("ddlLocation"));
            Label lblLocationLabel = ((Label)gvr.FindControl("lblLocationLabel"));

            conn.Close();
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmdLocationNames = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Billers WHERE Store = '" + 1 + "' ORDER BY Name ASC", conn);
            List<string> internalLocationsList = new List<string>();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdLocationNames.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string interlocations = reader.GetString(0);
                    internalLocationsList.Add(interlocations);
                }
                foreach (string locname in internalLocationsList)
                {
                    ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem(locname));
                    conn.Close();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }

            conn.Close();

        }

  //EDIT: if (lblLocationLabel.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                 ddlLocation.SelectedValue = lblLocationLabel.Text;
            }
    }
```

So, I used an SqlDataReader and then I add the "Billers" to the list. Once that happens, I add the listItems to the Drop Down List.

What I had to do for it to select properly was Bind the text to a label, then say..

ddlLocation.SelectedValue = lblLabelLocation.Text;

Don't Forget to put the OnRowDataBound in your gridview properties as well. I hope this helps.

EDIT:

This is how I did it. I used an if statement to check to see if that label's text length is not blank (I have a blank field in my drop down) and if it does have text, then select or show the value.. I made the edit above but here it is again.

```
protected void gvVehicle_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvVehicleTEMP.Rows)
        {
            DropDownList ddlLocation = ((DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("ddlLocation"));
            Label lblLocationLabel = ((Label)gvr.FindControl("lblLocationLabel")); //add this line to find the label

            conn.Close();
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmdLocationNames = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Billers WHERE Store = '" + 1 + "' ORDER BY Name ASC", conn);
            List<string> internalLocationsList = new List<string>();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdLocationNames.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string interlocations = reader.GetString(0);
                    internalLocationsList.Add(interlocations);
                }
                foreach (string locname in internalLocationsList)
                {
                    ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem(locname));
                    conn.Close();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }

            conn.Close();

        }

      if (lblLocationLabel.Text.Length > 0)//Added if statement
            {
                 ddlLocation.SelectedValue = lblLocationLabel.Text;
            }
    }
```

I use a templatefield like so.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Received">
           <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false">
                  </asp:DropDownList>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblLocationLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                              <font size="2">Received On: </font>
           </ItemTemplate>
           <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I hope this cleared it up a bit.

Comment: I got it working doing something similar to what you have above but when I try to set SelectedValue='<%# Eval("ResolutionCategory") %>'  I get error:  "'selResolutionCategory' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items."   But I know it does by querying the database    There is no way to just do it similar to the above (this works for text boxes)

Comment: not that I know of. Had the same issue. That is why I made a label- set it the visible property to false, then used the ddlDropDownList.SelectedValue = lblLabel.Text; I was tired of messing with it and knew this would work.

Comment: How do I do that with the full code I have above?  I am using bound fields, and template fields for editing.

Comment: Take a look at that edit. I gave you my complete code with the asp. You do have to use a TemplateField the way that I did it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. You don't appear to be populating the DropDownList with id `selResolutionSeverity` and
2. Your FindControl() won't work at the parent control level (you need to first locate the row being updated)

I suggest you simplify the program by using data binding.  If you are able to create a DataSource (e.g. SqlDataSource) for the severities, then you won't need to put any specific logic in the code behind.  The following example assumes you have a `SqlDataSource` in your page called `dsSeverities`.  If you don't wish to go down this route, then you could alternatively populate the DropDownList within a RowDataBound event handler.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Severity">
 <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
 <ItemTemplate>
   <%# Eval("ResolutionSeverity")%>
 </ItemTemplate>

 <EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:DropDownList  ID="selResolutionSeverity" runat="server"
     DataSourceID="dsSeverities"
     DataTextField="Description"
     DataValueField="ID"
     SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ResolutionSeverity") %>'  />
 </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the `DropDownList` in the `GridViewRow` which is in **Edit mode** on `GridView`'s `OnRowDataBound` event.

Here's how you can do this:

In markup add a method to `GridView`'s OnDtatBound. :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
    ... ... ...
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
```

Now in the code write your `GridView1_RowDataBound` method write this code ( I would highly recommend replacing the query string with parameterized query to prevent possible sql injection) :

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Make sure the row is in edit mode to find controls in EditItemTemlates
    if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) && ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0))
    {

        var ddl = GridView1.FindControl("selResolutionSeverity") as DropDownList;
        if (ddl != null)
        {

            // Consider using parameterized query to prevent possible sql injection
            string sSQL = @"SELECT ErrorTypeLookupID as Value, ErrorDescription as DisplayText
                            FROM BabelFish.dbo.ErrorTypeLookup (NOLOCK)
                            WHERE ErrorType = 'Severity' ";

            DataSet DS = new DatabaseAccessing.DatabaseConnection().DS(sSQL);
            ddl.DataSource = DS;
            ddl.DataTextField = "DisplayText";
            ddl.DataValueField = "Value";
            ddl.DataBind();
            ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select --", "0"));
        }
    }
}
```